# Kindly reopen "How do I remove this white space between text"?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [How do I remove this white space between text?](https://superuser.com/questions/1426313/how-do-i-remove-this-white-space-between-text)

I edited it.

Comment: Your edit automatically puts it into a review queue for reopening.  I left a comment on the question.  To be answerable, you will need to provide a lot of settings detail.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the act of editing your question put it into a review queue for assessment.

In this case your question was reviewed and voted to leave closed. [Review link](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/857803)

Simply editing your question is not enough. You should provide a detailed explanation of the problem which relies on external objects as little as possible.

Asking people to download a random file from an unknown source is a massive problem in this day and age due to the prevalence of exploits and advice saying never to run files you don't trust. Due to that the chances are slim that anyone will see the content in order to see the problem first hand.

Your habit of writing small text over images also limits how much help people can give. You do not tell us how you got into this position nor how to replicate it without downloading your file.

There are a number of useful comments on your question suggesting things you can do to improve it. The first thing to do would be to read those comments and take any advice given.